# disable administrator role in add user form

Tags: 7

Some role in my site has permission to create users but not a administrator one.
How to disable create a new user of administrator role?
Is there a module for that?
thanks.

Comment: I haven't used it but [User protect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) sounds like it might do the trick

Comment: @abd did you find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module that uses a hook, something like

```
function remove_admin_role_choice_from_add_user_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['roles'][3]['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```